# How do I access a factory inside my module config?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I am setting custom headers in my module configuration. These headers are dynamic and they call upon the a factory to get their value.

How do I access my factory inside of the configuration? I understand that on the config, it might not be ready/available, but when my headers are computed, it will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give us code ! In this example instead of factory provider is used,to configure value of salutation variable.

```
provide.provider('greeter2', function() {
  var salutation = 'Hello';
  this.setSalutation = function(s) {
    salutation = s;
  }

  function Greeter(a) {
    this.greet = function() {
      return salutation + ' ' + a;
    }
  }

  this.$get = function(a) {
    return new Greeter(a);
  };
});



angular.module('abc', []).configure(function(greeter2Provider) {
  greeter2Provider.setSalutation('Halo');
});
```

your question is not clear,i cant even fully understand it,but maybe that code somehow can help you...